# Stream API modify list while processing

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a `Stream<List<Integer>>` which i receive and have no control of the generating api. The lists have at most 4 elements. But some have fewer than 4 elements but guaranteed at least one. I need to modify and add zeros to the list to make all lists have the same size = 4.

Just as an example, in reality i don't have a list.

```
List<List<Integer>> myList = List.of(List.of(1,2,3,4),
                                     List.of(7,5),
                                     List.of(2,9),
                                     List.of(1));

Stream<List<Integer>> myStream = myList().stream();
```

I need for further processing same sized lists of length 4, so the above list should look like `[1,2,3,4],[7,5,0,0],[2,9,0,0],[1,0,0,0]`. Preferably I want to do it without collecting the stream in intermediate result list. My naive approach don't work, because list.add returns a boolean not a list and doesn't take into account how many zeros to add.

```
myStream.map(list -> list.size() == 4 ? list : list.add(0)
```

How to achieve the desired result?

If possible I want to avoid:

```
List<List<Integer> collected = myStream.collect(toList());

for(List<Integer> temp : collected){
   if(temp.size() < 4){
      for(int i= 0; i < 4 - temp.size(); i++){
          temp.add(0);
      }
   }
}


myStream = collected.stream();
```

Comment: The list returned by List.of is immutable so you need to create more lists. You can't edit those ones.

Comment: Note that you can have multiple statements in a lambda, e.g. `map( list -> { if( list.size() == 4 ) return list; else /*create a new list, add zeros as needed and return it*/ })`.

Comment: Can I map somehow to a new List and copy existing elements and possibly adding zeros to have a guaranteed length of 4?

Comment: Sure you can, e.g. `map(list -> new ArrayList<>(list))`. If you provide a method to add missing zeros it could then be something like `map(list ->pad( new ArrayList<>(list), 4, () -> 0))` with pad having a signature like `<T> List<T> pad(List<T> list, int minSize, Supplier<T> defaultElementSupplier))`.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you very much. Will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stream API is very much not about modifying anything, but about transforming (as in, mapping one object to another). In that sense, you want either the stream to just magically grow zeroes, or, to transform your input list of e.g. `[7, 5]` into an entirely new list/streamable concept containing `[7, 5, 0, 0]`. Once you start modifying your inputs, streams just grow an endless series of warts, caveats, and errors - it's not what they are for, you're now buttering your toast with a clawhammer, which might be possible, but isn't a good idea - go get your butter knife.

Fortunately, your job description isn't fundamentally about modifying those inputs, so that's not a showstopper.

So many ways to accomplish this goal. Pick your poison:

### Make a class to represent the notion of padded-up lists.

```
myList.stream().map(list -> new PaddedList(list, 0, 4))....
```

is all you need, but you'd have to write PaddedList yourself, which would take a bit of effort. It would look like this, but I've left out quite a bit of it:

```
public class PaddedList<T> extends AbstractList<T> {
    private final List<T> source;
    private final int padSize;
    private final T padElem;

    public T get(int idx) {
        return (idx < 0 || idx >= padSize || source.size() > idx) ? 
          source.get(idx) : padElem;
    }

    public int size() {
        return Math.max(padSize, source.size());
    }
}
```

### `map` your input list to size it up

```
myList.stream().map(list -> {
    if (list.size() >= 4) return list;
    var out = new ArrayList<Integer>(list);
    while (out.size() < 4) out.add(0);
    return out;
})....
```

### That but let's go golfing

```
myList.stream().map(list -> Arrays.asList(list.toArray(new Integer[4])))....
```

### Many, many, many more options

Especially if you don't necessarily need the output to be in list form, (e.g. if it can be in iterable form, or as a stream).

However, there is no 'pad it up' equivalent in the stream API. There's a pad-it-down (`.limit(4)`, for example), but not the reverse.

Comment: Wow. I did not expect such a detailed answer. Thank you very much. The task is only marginally related to my actual usecase, so I will probably not implement my own PaddedList. I find your "size it up" and "golfing" solution good and understandable. Thanks again for the many suggestions and overall very helpful answer.